# a library makes my project slower

Tags: android, android-library, android-mvvm

I new in android app development.I have build simple android library which having class base activity **BaseActivity**

i have upload library to github : https://github.com/ubheamar/android_core/

now i am trying to use jitpack to get library for android project.
`implementation 'com.github.ubheamar:android_core:master-SNAPSHOT'`

but when i using this library in my  another project android studio gets slow.

Comment: `android studio gets slow` what exactly gets slow in it?

Comment: when i try to use android studio editor
1.its showing error like after 20 sec
2.Intellisense not showing or taking time